# Is the jewellery in the 2016 adaptation of War and Peace genuine?

Tags: props, war-and-peace

I've been watching the [2016 BBC adaptation](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3910804/) of Tolstoy's *War and Peace*, and also reading about it on the internet between episodes. One of the rumours I've come across is that **the jewellery used on set was genuine**: the actresses were actually wearing real gems and diamonds during filming.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Is this true? If so, where did this jewellery come from - was it borrowed from a special collection somewhere, or was some of it even custom-made?

<sub>Canonical answers only please: interviews and reliable sources.</sub>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's more information (about the jewellery seen in War and Peace) than anyone could sensibly need on [this website](http://war-and-peace.rbth.com/3/)

> *Shot on location in Russia, Lithuania and other Eastern European
> countries, characters are seen wearing jewelry made by Russian jeweler
> Petr Axenoff.*
>
> *Part of the collection was made specifically for the TV series. Other
> items were selected by Gibbon's team from existing collections. "We
> were surprised by their choice because the jewelry they selected was
> from a later period, specifically art nouveau. When I was making those
> items, I was inspired by completely different things," Axenoff says.*

Based on interviews with the show's makers on the [BBC blog](http://www.bbc.co.uk/blogs/tv/entries/4ac5a723-5c93-4ea2-aec1-3bf0a57a035d), it would seem that they also supplemented the Axenoff items with paste jewelry and some bits and bobs from the BBCs own prop archive:

> *Jewellery is still all about impact and making a statement. For me in
> War and Peace it's a great way to accessorise the very simple gowns
> that we wanted to create - free from too much surface decoration and
> unnecessary ornamentation. The jewels were sourced from all around the
> world. From Indian markets in Southall, flea markets in Lithuania, St.
> Petersburg, Prague and Rome to beautiful pieces designed especially
> for us by a Russian jeweller.*
>
> *The action of the story takes place at such an interesting time for
> fashion. It is where we see the birth of modern fashion as we
> understand it today. The aftermath of the French Revolution saw people
> turning their back on formal aristocratic styles. And this was coupled
> with Napoleon’s visionary ideas to create more revenue for French
> fabrics by creating the fashion seasons, changing four times a year as
> they do today. And fashion is cyclical, everything goes round.*
>
> <sub><sup>*"Edward K Gibbon is the costume designer for War and Peace."*</sup></sub>